# How to add global functions in Laravel webpack.mix.js?

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I am using Laravel mix to compile my assets and combining them into single file. I created a new js file and wrote some methods in this. I combined this file with app.js file. From my blade file when i try to call those methods i get an error `function not defined` . I am unable to access those methods.

Please help me out to call those methods.

**Laravel Mix code**

```
mix.js([ 'js/app.js',
         'js/custom.js'
        ], 'public/js'),
.....
```

**Custom.js**

```
function test(){
  alert('test')
}
```

**test.blade.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    test();
</script>
```

> Error : test is not defined

Comment: Is `app.js` included before you try to use `test();`?

Comment: Yes, When i view the source code for app.js, The method exist in app.js at very bottom of app.js. Other events are working but function is not accessible.

Comment: Are you including the file above `test()`? I don't see `<script src="app.js"></script>` anywhere in `test.blade.php`

Comment: Actually it is added in test.blade.php but i forgot to inform you. Now post updated.

Answer (score 9):

Just assign it to **window**. So in your Custom.js

```
window.test = function(){
  alert('test')
}
```

and use it in your test.blade.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.test();
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

**custom.js**

```
function test(){
    alert('test')
}

export { test };
```

**app.js**

```
...
import { test } from './custom.js';
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than just concatenating the new file onto the end of the `app.js` a cleaner approach (imho) is to leave your `webpack.mix.js` untouched.

Create your `custom.js` file in `resources/assets/js` and simply add `require('./custom');` at the bottom of `resources/assets/js/app.js`

This will then be required as part of the rest of the build process.

Comment: "This is not working" is not helpful. If you want assistance you need to provide as much information as possible. I've done exactly what I suggested above in 3 projects in the last month without any issues.